# Given that $AX=B$ has a unique solution, is it possible that the row rank of $A$ is less than $4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $AX=B$ has a unique solution, where $A$ is $4\times 3$ matrix, $X$ is a $3\times 1$ column vector and $B$ is a $4\times 1$ column vector, is it possible that one row of the matrix $A$ is the linear combination of other three rows?

Comment: rizwan ahmed, shouldn't $B$ be a $4\times 1$ vector/ matrix? (for multiplication confirmation)

Comment: @Apurv Yes, but $X$ should certainly still be a $3\times 1$ vector, so your edit was incorrect.

Comment: @TomOldfield, I didn't note that $X$ and $B$ were written together. My mistake.

Comment: @Apurv No problem, just letting you know why I rejected the edit.

Comment: Can you think of an example of a 4x3 matrix A where one row is not a linear combination of the other 3?

Comment: The rank of a $4\times3$ matrix is _always_ less than $4$, so the answer to the question in the title is that it is not only possible, it is even inevitable, and that without using any other hypothesis than the given size of$~A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\text{span}(\text{Row}_1, \text{Row}_2, \text{Row}_3) \ne \mathbb{R}^3$, then one of them can be written as the linear combination of the other 2.

If $\text{span}(\text{Row}_1, \text{Row}_2, \text{Row}_3) = \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\text{Row}_4 \in \text{span}(\text{Row}_1, \text{Row}_2, \text{Row}_3)$, so $\text{Row}_4$ may be written as a linear combination of the other $3$ rows.